# Ist das Verb „schaffen“ eine Beleidigung in Bayern?

Tags: meaning, dialect, bavarian

Jemand aus Bayern hat mir gesagt, dass das Verb *schaffen* eine Bedeutung im Sinne von *Sex mit jemandem haben* habe, also wenn ich mit jemandem aus diesem Gebiet spreche, vermeide ich, dieses Tätigkeitswort zu benutzen. Außer die Bedeutung von *vögeln* zu haben, bedeutet es sonstwas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ich kenne viele Wörter, die eine Bedeutung unter der Bettdecke haben, aber *schaffen* gehört **nicht** dazu. Vielleicht ist es regional begrenzt auf Ost-/Nordostbayern, oder vielleicht ist es jüngere oder ältere Jugendsprache, das kann ich nicht bestätigen. Aber *ich* würde es so *nicht* verstehen.

*Schaffen* bedeutet einerseits – mein Bairisch ist nicht weit weg vom Schwäbischen – *arbeiten,* andererseits auch *gelingen.* Man könnte sich in beide Bedeutungen eine Übertragung in Richtung waagrechtes Vergnügen hineindichten, aber wie schon erwähnt ist sie mir noch nicht untergekommen.

Ganz anders ist das Verb *anschaffen:* Mit Dativobjekt (*jemandem etwas anschaffen*) bedeutet es *einen Auftrag erteilen,* transitiv (*etwas anschaffen*) bedeutet es *besorgen,* aber ohne Objekt (nur *anschaffen;* meist in der Zusammenfügung *anschaffen gehen*) bedeutet es *sich prostituieren.*

---

Anmerkung: In einem Kommentar hat Hubert bestätigt, dass diese Wörter in Österreich (wo auch bairische Dialekte gesprochen werden) genau so verstanden werden.

Comment: Stimmt auch zu 100 % mit dem österreichischen Sprachgebrauch überein.